# How do I use a standard distribution to guess where the value falls in the future?

Tags: excel, statistics, modeling, normal-distribution, vba

I have a mean value x and I want to model it into the future. I want to output a value of what it could be in 6 months. Assuming the value follows a normal distribution and we have the standard deviation how do I randomize the value x while following a normal distribution? I'm doing this in excel, but just understanding it would help too! Basically I want to produce numbers 68% of the time within 1 deviation, 95% of the time withing 2 deviation etc. etc.

Comment: We need to know the mean of the distribution too.

Comment: Apologize. X is the mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Produce random numbers with specific distribution with Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241784/produce-random-numbers-with-specific-distribution-with-excel)

Comment: I believe the Norminv will actually just give a uniform type distribution. RAND() is just a uniform 0-1

Comment: Basically I want to produce numbers 68% of the time within 1 deviation, 95% of the time withing 2 deviation etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excel function 'NORMINV' to convert a random input 'RAND()' to a normal distribution.

```
=NORMINV(RAND(),Mean,Std Dev)
```

i.e. if you repeat this many times, save and analyze the results, you'll see a bell curve over the input Mean value.

Does that get you started?

The tricky bit comes when you come up with the formula to predict what a value will be in the future using this.